# Jenkins and Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

We are trying to set up a devop for our project. 
While configuring maven in jenkins, it is noted that jkenkins is not considering the maven repository configured in the settings.xml.

We have noticed the following statements from the console:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\apps\Jenkins\jobs\SCAVENGER\workspace
Updating http://localhost/project1/scavenger-new at revision '2016-03-21T13:49:29.211 -0700'
At revision 5



No changes for http://localhost/project1/scavenger-new since the previous build
Parsing POMs
Downloaded artifact https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/io/dropwizard/dropwizard-bom/0.9.1/dropwizard-bom-0.9.1.pom
Downloaded artifact https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/io/dropwizard/dropwizard-parent/0.9.1/dropwizard-parent-0.9.1.pom
Downloaded artifact https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.22.1/jersey-bom-2.22.1.pom
Downloaded artifact https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/net/java/jvnet-parent/4/jvnet-parent-4.pom
Established TCP socket on 52263
[workspace] $ C:\apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -cp C:\apps\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.7.jar;C:\apps\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.2.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\apps\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main C:\apps\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.2.5 C:\apps\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.56.jar C:\apps\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar C:\apps\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 52263
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\apps\Jenkins\jobs\SCAVENGER\workspace\pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\apps\Jenkins\jobs\SCAVENGER\workspace\.repository install
```

My build is failing as our local repository holds some artifacts which are not available in maven central.

The local repository configuration in our settings.xml :

```
<localRepository>C:\apps\MAVEN\repo\local</localRepository>
```

In jenkins, we configured maven as 
[image]

How can can we configure the Jenkins to consider the local repository rather than creating a new one for the same. Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last option in your screenshot, Local Maven Repository, it's a drop down list, you would have additional entries:

- Local to the executor
- Local to the workspace
- Default (pointing at the one picked up from your settings)

In your case is selected *Local to the workspace*, which is not the behavior you actually wanted. **Change it to the Default one**.

That's also the reason why Jenkins is passing to maven the following:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=C:\apps\Jenkins\jobs\SCAVENGER\workspace\.repository
```

The repository is always related to the workspace of the concerned job, according to the selected option above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. We have one more issue related to sonarqube. Have installed and started sonarqube also have configured the same through jenkins. But it seems sonarqube is not showing any data related to the build. Not sure where we went wrong.

Comment: @kallada this is way too broad to troubleshoot via comments :) I would suggest to create another question and provide details about versions involved (sonarqube, plugins) and errors details